# Rust cannot return value referencing local variable

Tags: rust

I guess this is a quite basic Rust question, but I have this piece of code

```
struct Stock<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    value: u8,
}
impl<'a> Stock<'a> {
    fn read(file: &mut File) -> Stock<'a> {
        let mut value = vec![0; 1];
        file.read(&mut value);
        let name_size = read_u32(file);
        let mut name = vec![0; name_size as usize];
        file.read(&mut name);
        return Stock {
            name: str::from_utf8(&name).unwrap(),
            value: value[0],
        };
    }
}
```

and of course, it doesn't work, because I am referencing a local value name. To my limited knowledge, this is because outside the scope of `read`, `name` doesn't exist. However wouldn't `from_utf8` create a new variable that is not scoped to `read`?

Also, I've read a bit about other people with this issue, and the suggestion is always to switch to the owned `String`. But why can't I do something such as `name: str::from_utf8(&name).unwrap().to_owned()`?

Comment: [Here's how you might use `String`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e31965f9a799dc5aca26360538cf630f) (with some other improvements).

Comment: Re: *But why can't I do something such as `name: str::from_utf8(&name).unwrap().to_owned()`?* Yes, and that gives you a `String`. I'm not sure I understand the objection here. Just use `String`.

Comment: The objection is me not yet understanding the language and didn't fully understand that `to_owned` would give me a `String` :) But yeah, I feel like your answers are helping quite a bit (especially the code sample). I just need to fully understand them

Answer (score 2):

> However wouldn't `from_utf8` create a new variable that is not scoped to read?

No, it gives you a borrow with the same lifetime as the one you pass.

Even if it created a new variable, you would have to tie it to somewhere, like the scope of `read()`, so again you would have the same problem.

The issue is that your `Stock` struct holds a reference. That means whatever it points to it has to live for all the time `Stock` is alive. But any variables you create in the local scope of `read()` will die when `read()` ends.

Instead, what you want is for `Stock` to own the value so that it keeps alive it itself.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely should change the struct field to `name: String` and get rid of the `'a` lifetime parameter.